# HTTP logging in IE8 developer tools?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

Is there a way to do http logging in this like I can do in fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Firebug lite can log XHR requests.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Fiddler.  That's what it is there for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Http Watch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) as a HTTP traffing sniffer, it has plugin for both IE and FF.

Answer (score 0):

[dynaTrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/) is a free app for Internet Explorer that does HTTP logging.